# Create subqueries for each value in a Column

Tags: sql

I'm looking to create a SQL query that answers the following question: "Which was the most common destination airport in each month?" The table is structured such that it has Month and Destination_Airport columns (amongst other things), and I'm hoping for the query result to look like the following:

| Month | Destination_Airport |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | JFK |
| 2 | LAX |
| 3 | BOS |
| 4 | MIA |
| and | so on |

I've tried this query `SELECT Month, Destination_Airport FROM Flight GROUP BY Month, Destination_Airport ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC` which gets me all of the Month, Destination_Airport pairs ordered by their frequency, but I don't know how to trim it down to only return the most popular airport per month, and nothing more. Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track.  You can then use window functions to get the top per month:

```
SELECT md.*
FROM (SELECT Month, Destination_Airport, COUNT(*) as cnt,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Month ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM Flight
      GROUP BY Month, Destination_Airport 
     ) md
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

this will solve the purpose:
Note: if two airports have same number of occurrences for the same month, both will show.

```
;with T1 as 
(select distinct months,destination_airport, 
count(destination_airport)  as 'Counts'
from dbo.flight
group by  months,destination_airport ),
T2 as 
(select max(Counts) as Counts, months from T1 group by months)

select months, destination_airport from 
T1 where concat(T1.months,T1.Counts) in (select concat(months,Counts) from t2)
```